# using nohup -> output to file and console

Tags: linux, console, output, nohup

iam using nohup in my project. 
Is there a possibility get the Output of the program to the console and to the file at the same time while using nohup?

With "tee"i had no sucess:

```
nohup ./programm 2>&1 | tee Output.txt
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this to run and log the output in file.

```
nohup ./program  > Output.txt | tail -F Output.txt &
```

If you want to run it in background:

```
nohup ./program  > Output.txt &
```

Comment: Don`t work. Writes only in the file. But on the  Console (stdout) is no Output.

Comment: that is the solution i tried before. 
The Problem is at the end of the program the Output of the console stops and dont goes back to the Linux user prompt. So i have to shutdown the Report with strg -c to go back to the Linux user prompt.  I Need a solution where it goes back to the Linux user prompt when the program is finish.

Comment: I think its quiet confusing.. you want this to run tail in background so that you can access the console prompt again. Is it ?

Comment: Yes, but i read the prompt with a own written Software tool from another pc. 
So when the tool on Linux console with tail -f is finished,  i have to Close the prompt with strg -c to go back to the Linux user prompt.
I want to avoid the STRG-C Command because  i want to set new commands to the Linux console with my own written software

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please have a look whether it is working by putting an & at the end to make it runnable as background. I hope it should work

Comment: Thanks this solution works for me.!!! Can you explain what the command excatly do?

Comment: It actually logs into ouptut.txt and tail will be used to read the file but this reading process will be executed in background. this '&' means run the process in background.